# Every sets of values in a record should be unique?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, postgis, plpgsql

I have a database storing a pair of x,y coordinates on each records.  I have already generated 1000 points.  However, how can I make sure there's no duplicate points in the database? (I want to populate a fixed number of points in that coordinate system and am trying avoid using postgres point type.)

Comment: In MySQL one can put a unique index over the (x,y) column pair. Perhaps postgre has a similar feature.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'postgre'.

Answer (score 1):

Add unique constraint on both columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_tab ON tab (x, y);
```